# I'm getting this error cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')

Tags: react-router

I'm trying to implement navigation to a new page by pushing it to the history but i'm having this error **TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')** please I need some help on this please.

This is my code and i was expecting it to redirect me to the App.js file

```
import React from "react";
import {getFunName} from '../helpers'

class StorePicker extends React.Component {

  myInput = React.createRef()

  goToStore = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    const storeName = this.myInput.current.value

    this.props.history.push(`/store/${storeName}`)
   
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form className="store-selector" onSubmit={this.goToStore}>
        <h2>Please enter a store</h2>
        <input type="text" ref={this.myInput} placeholder="Store Name" defaultValue={getFunName()}/>
        <button type="submit">Visit Store</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
export default StorePicker;
```

This my Router.js file

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import StorePicker from './StorePicker'
import App from './App'
import NotFound from './NotFound'

const Router = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/" element={<StorePicker/>} />
            <Route path="/store/:storeId" element={<App />} />
            <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
        </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
)
export default Router
```